# Swift JSONDecoder decode get element original data

Tags: swift, decode, jsondecoder

Define a struct A like:

```
struct A: Codable {
    let value1: String
    let value2: String
}
```

```
let a: A = A(value1: "1", value2: "2")
let aData: Data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(a)
let aStr: String = String(data: aData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(aStr)

let jsonString = "{\"value2\":\"2\",\"value1\":\"1\"}"
let jsonData: Data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let a1 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(A.self, from: jsonData)
print(a1)

let arrayString = "[{\"value2\":\"2\",\"value1\":\"1\"}]"
let arrayData: Data = arrayString.data(using: .utf8)!
let aArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([A].self, from: arrayData)
print(aArray)
```

now give you a string: arrayString

`let arrayString = "[{"value2":"2","value1":"1"}]"`

`let arrayData: Data = arrayString.data(using: .utf8)!`

without `JSONDecoder` to `aArray` then get `aArray.first`, then `JSONEncoder` to `aData`

and don't `replace` the `"["`, `"]"` to `""`

how can I get aData directly from Decoder?

```
struct B: Codable {
    let aData: Data
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // can I get aData from decoder or container directly?
        // I want to get it this way, is it possible?
    }
}

try? JSONDecoder().decode([B].self, from: arrayData)
or?
try? JSONDecoder().decode(B.self, from: arrayData)
or some way using Decoder?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for Swift Reflection

Comment: So you want to get JSON data... from JSON data? Why? How is that useful? Isn't getting an instance of `A` much more useful? Whatever way you use, it is going to involve parsing the JSON, and encoding the JSON again. What's wrong with this approach? Otherwise, it's just direct string manipulation, like replacing the `[]`, like you said.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using a `JSONDecoder` because, by the time you get to B's `init(from Decoder:)` the element of the array has already been parsed into a dictionary. It may be possible to decode it as an `A` and then re-encode it in `B`'s `init`

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "without JSONDecoder to aArray then get aArray.first, then JSONEncoder to aData" - it's very confusing